# How to get Primary Dns Suffix programmatically?

Tags: c#, dns

How to retrive Primary Dns Suffix programmatically in c#?

> ```
> C:\Users\jdoe>ipconfig /all
>
> Windows IP Configuration
>
>    Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : ABC-PC
>    --->Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : mdanshin.co.za<---
>    Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
>    IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
>    WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
>    DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : mdanshin.co.za
> ```

Comment: [`IPInterfaceProperties.DnsSuffix`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipinterfaceproperties.dnssuffix(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

So, Alex K's answer is not correct (sorry).  That will give you the connection specific DNS information which can be different for each adapter.  Consider the configuration below.  One adapter will give a different answer.

The correct answer is:

```
 var primaryDnsSuffix = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName;
```

That will return the value in the line that says "Primary Dns Suffix"

[IPInterfaceProperties.DnsSuffix Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ipinterfaceproperties.dnssuffix)

**Multi-homed ipconfig /all output:**

> ```
> Windows IP Configuration
>
>    Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : BOB
>    Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : fred.george.com
>    Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Peer-Peer
>    IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
>    WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
>    DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : fred.george.com
>                                        george.com
>
> PPP adapter Harry:
>
>    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : fred.george.com
>    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Harry
>    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :
>    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
>    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
>    IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.2(Preferred)
>    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
>    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0
>    DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
>    Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.100
>    Secondary WINS Server . . . . . . : 192.168.1.101
>    NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
>
>    Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:
>
>    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : ron.george.com
>    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek USB GbE Family Controller #2
>    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 6B-21-CD-65-AC-25
>    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
>    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
>    IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.3(Preferred)
>    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
>    Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Friday, August 30, 2019 10:29:34 AM
>    Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, September 05, 2019 2:36:12 PM
>    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
>    DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
>    DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.102
>                                        192.168.1.103
>    NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
>    Connection-specific DNS Suffix Search List :
>                                        george.com
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You could run the command and redirect to an output file ipconfig /all > c:\temp\ipconfig-results.txt
and then parse the output txt file to extract what you are looking for.
(sorry I don't know c# to provide some code how to do this)